# Erro com o jQuery ColorPicker

Tags: jquery

estou usando o [jQuery ColorPicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/) só que esta dando o seguinte error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ColorPicker'

O meu codigo esta assim:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="colorpicker/js/eye.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="colorpicker/js/utils.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="style-colors">
            <div class="cores">
                <label for="">Cor</label>
                <div class="sc-background">
                    <div style="background-color: #0000ff"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.sc-background').ColorPicker();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar com esse erro?

Comment: Entre aqui > http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/

Comment: esse é muito grande, fica feio, tem que ser algo mais sutil @SamirBraga

Comment: O erro que você está a receber dá-me a ideia que o ficheiro .js não carregou. Pode confirmar se o seu url está correcto?

Answer (score 1):

Eu baixei o pacote do jQuery ColorPicker e vi que o arquivo jQuery que vem nele é a versão 1.3.2.

A versão 1.10 tem mudanças grandes em relação à 1.3.2, então tente carregar o arquivo jQuery do pacote que é baixado junto com o jQuery ColorPicker, a 1.3.2 para confirmar se o problema não é causado por isso.

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ColorPicker'

Esse erro ocorreu porque a biblioteca ColorPicker não foi incluida corretamente, eu recomendo ao contrário de usar uma biblioteca use o "novo input" `<input type="color" />` com um Polyfill como o [Spectrum](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) por exemplo.

Além disso, eu achei na Wikipédia do jQuery UI um artigo falando sobre isso, ([aqui](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137750/ColorPicker)), ele cita algumas bibliotecas que devem se encaixar nas suas preferências.